# Adobe Air - Hardware Acceleration & Render Mode

Tags: android, performance, flash, air, adobe

I have two flash pieces: the **Shell** and the **Content**. The Shell is an Air 3.8 for Android project - the Content is a Flash 11.8 project. The Shell runs on an android device and loads in the Content .swf. Between the two of them I have three groups of hardware acceleration options:

1. **Shell** > Publish Settings > Hardware acceleration

   1. None
   2. Level 1 - Direct
   3. Level 2 - GPU
2. **Shell** > Air settings > Render mode

   1. Auto
   2. CPU
   3. GPU
   4. Direct
3. **Content** > Publish Settings > Hardware acceleration

   1. None
   2. Level 1 - Direct
   3. Level 2 - GPU

... which is a lot of different possible combinations of setting to test when trying to figure out what performs best.

Are any of those settings rendered moot by others? Does the Shell's 'Hardware acceleration' trump the Content's? Does the Shell's 'Render mode' trump both the others?

tl;dr: does an air app's render mode override its hardware acceleration, and do either of those override the hardware acceleration of a .swf that's loaded into the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I am mistaken, only the app ("Shell") render mode matters in this case. A non-GPU accelerated SWF should be accelerated in a GPU accelerated app. Easy way to find out in Flash would be to create a SWF that has a filter (`DropShadowFilter` works) and load it in a GPU-accelerated app. If the filter doesn't work, this is correct (filters don't work in GPU render mode). So, basically, the only mode that matters is the highest level container's render mode.

Regardless, the linguistic differences (`Render Mode` vs `Hardware Acceleration`) are absolutely the same. GPU = GPU, Direct = Direct, None = CPU. Auto is also currently CPU (originally, it was meant to auto select the best mode, but it has yet to be implemented)

Comment: so basically they override eachother in the following order: Shell Render Mode > Shell Hardware Acceleration > Module Hardware Acceleration, right? I need to to some more testing but so far that *is* seeming to be the case.

Comment: yeah, looks like the shell's air settings definitely override the other two. alright cool, good to know.

Comment: Yeah. Look at it as children inheriting settings from their parents. Like in iOS, if you have location tracking enabled in an app's settings, but disabled for the app in the System Settings, it is disabled for the app.

Comment: You can always check what rendering mode you're using by checking wmodeGPU attribute on Stage. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#wmodeGPU